# .net deploy complex application

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

We have developed a small tool sets and we have a lot of issues in deploy phase.

We have:

N° 1 app that run on server as service (console). Here, we use xcopy.

N° 1 app over 10 PC, this is the active part of the system (ex: measure, scan, print). We use ClickOnce, because theoretically, it keeps update all but it's a hell, with a wide range of issue.

N° 1/2 apps run over some machines that help the operators to make them jobs (ex: picking).

Obviously, all the apps must be rebuild every time we made some new patches.

Someone can suggest the best way to make smartly this process.
We are thinking about use Jenkins to build the code every night but there's a lot of issue due the deploy.

We tried use the classic msi but the cost of installation is very high.

Platform .net 4.0 (c#) with visual studio 2015

Some suggestion?

Comment: Do all of the end machines have internet access? If so, you're options are immense :D

Comment: You are not supposed to ask for software recommendations on StackOverflow because they tend to generate spam. See [No.4 on 'What questions can I ask'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). StackExchange has a different site for this type of question called SoftwareRecommendations one which there is [a similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/40176/open-source-deployment-manager-for-windows-10-applications-files-and-database/40177).